# Using a css bundle of multiple files with webpack and Angular2

Tags: angular, sass, less, webpack

This question is relevant to using both less and sass as far as I know.

Webpack has an issue when bundling multiple style files, and trying to load other files within the CSS files using the `url()` method in CSS.
The issue is described here: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/27

The official answer is to use `extract-text-webpack-plugin`. But this won't work with Angular2, as it creates a CSS file instead of a string, and Angular2 only accepts strings in the `styles` attribute for components. (And it obviously won't work on `styleUrls` as well...)

What can be done here?

These are the relevant parts of my webpack config:

```
   {
     test: /\.less$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
       "raw-loader!css-loader!less-loader",
       {
         publicPath: "/assets"
       }
     )
   },

   // .......

  new ExtractTextPlugin("assets/[name].css?[hash]-[chunkhash]-[name]"),
```